# String.Split on VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to do a String.Split on VB.NET and it doesn't appear to work. Appreciate any help to see what I am missing:

In C#:

```
sFileContents = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
sLines = sFileContents.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In VB.NET:

```
sFileContents = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName)
sLines = sFileContents.Split(New String() {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

In C# I get the number of lines split correctly and in VB.NET I only get 1 line.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why not use `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadLines` instead?

Comment: `{ "\r\n" }` is not recognized as a CRLF pair in VB.  If you change to `ReadAllLines` you wont have to split - it returns an array of lines.

Comment: @juharr @Plutonix I need to split by a `\r\n` only not `\r` or `\n`. I may have a line with a \n at pos 30 but a \r\n at 100. I need the whole 100 in a line and not 2 lines 1 of 30 and 1 of 70

Comment: @Gusman I ge the following error:
Bounds can be specified only for the top-level array when initializing an array of arrays.

Comment: `New String() {Environment.NewLine}` should work

Comment: @Jeremy @Plutonix Ok. Both work. vbCRLF and Environment.NewLine. Is there any reason why the `\r\n` doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoSoto they are interpreted by the C# compiler as literals for carriage return and new line respectively. the VB compiler does not do that.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: @LeonardoSoto for fuller reference the C# spec shows all of the cases that the "\" escape characters works in C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences don't work in VB.NET.

You should use the VB.NET constants: vbCrLf, vbLf

```
sFileContents = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName)
Dim arg() As String = {vbCrLf, vbLf}
sLines = sFileContents.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Although the previous answer also solves the problem as this one. I accepted this answer as at least tells me that Escape sequences don't work in VB. Would love to know why not though.

Comment: @LeonardoSoto If you would refresh the page maybe... I had edited my answer about 5 min ago to include that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sFileContents = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName)
sLines = sFileContents.Split({ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Also, note that `New String()` is omitted in the code above. VB.NET can directly accept arrays in the form `{ <element>, <element> }`. So no need for the `New` keyword and the initializer.

You should, in fact use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) as you can never be certain about line-endings on different platforms.

In VB.NET, `"\r\n"` is interpreted as `"\r\n"` itself and not a `Carriage-Return + NewLine` as with C#. They are called special characters. VB.NET doesn't have any. It's only the double quotes which need escaping (by using pairs). For Example:

```vb
Dim result = "He said, ""This is some code.""" 'Yields : He said, "This is some code."
```

Another option would be to use predefined VB.NET constants like `vbCrLf` but I would say that `Environment.NewLine` is a better way.